# To understand php / javascript calling order?

Tags: javascript, php, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to understand clearly how a php file with html/javascript included via   executes and in what order.
The filename is pickme.php and displays the SELECT button, allows selection of Products via the resourcePicker. It does not display the returned result: selected (an array).

My example code is:

HTML snippet: (to display the SELECT Button)

```
Select the Products that you wish to include in the sale event.<br><br><button id="open-picker">Select Products</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT snippet: (to perform the ResourcePicker call. Results in 'selected')

```
<script>
    document
    .getElementById('open-picker')
    .addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const selected = await shopify.resourcePicker({type: 'product', multiple: true});
    Cookies.set("selected", selected, 300);
    console.log(selected);
    });
</script>
```

PHP to display **cookies**. (Hopefully the 'selected' result from the ResourcePicker call)

```
<?php

    /* read a cookie */
    $cookie = isset($_COOKIE["selected"])?$_COOKIE["selected"]:null;
  
    // Another way to debug/test is to view all cookies
    echo "  $_COOKIE </br>";
    print_r($_COOKIE);

    print_r($cookie);

    echo " $selected </br>";
    print_r($selected);
?>
```

The problem is that the results in the ending PHP section displays before the JAVASCRIPT 'await' finishes executing resulting in all zero results in $_COOKIE and $selected.

I am looking for a solution to overcome this situation. Thank you.

I have tried multiple debug sessions and changing the position of the PHP code to display the Cookie results with no success.

Comment: You are mixin up what is a server and a client language.
PHP - server language- run in the server machine and once that it "compiled" it return to the client.
Javascript - client side - get the file from the server and runs the script in the client machine

Comment: PHP runs on the server. It is finished running BEFORE the page ever renders.

Comment: Thank you both. I understand that now. However am still hoping for a recommendation on how to resolve this issue (i.e. how to display results after the javascript function).

Comment: Is your php and javascript in the same file? Even if so, you can try to send a http request to php from javascript, this way when you select from js it will send a request to your php server and then it will echo out your results

Comment: Thank you @Adi. I shall give that a try. Much appreciated.